# how write the loop in a line when character decoding fun in if

Tags: python

I am trying to write the loop in a line, the first code works but the second fails.

**first**

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import os
import re

def getIp():
    os.system('ipconfig /all > myip.txt')
    ipv4 =[]
    with open('myip.txt', 'r') as myip:
        for line in myip:
            line = line.decode('gbk')
            if re.match(u'   IPv4', line):
                ipv4.append(line)
    return ipv4

ip = getIp()
print ip[0]
```

**second**

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import os
import re

def getIp():
    os.system('ipconfig /all > myip.txt')
    ipv4 =[]
    with open('myip.txt', 'r') as myip:
        ipv4 = [line for line in myip if re.match((u'IPv4').encode('gbk'), line) ]# failed, return empty ipv4 list
        # ipv4 = [line.encode('gbk') for line in myip if re.match(u'IPv4', line.encode('gbk')) ]#failed, return empty ipv4 list
        # ipv4 = [line for line.encode('gbk') in myip if re.match(u'IPv4', line) ]# SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
    return ipv4

ip = getIp()
print ip[0]
```

I think, the cmd line in gbk, so I should decode it in gbk. it return a three length list in first, but return empty in second(failed).

Can you please help me make the second work?

Thanks.

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: Why bother with the list comprehension if your for loop works?

Answer (score 1):

In **first** you decode the line then try to find a match in it

```
line = line.decode('gbk')
if re.match(u'.....', line):
```

In **Second** you encode the pattern for the match.

```
re.match((u'IPv4').encode('gbk'), line)
```

Maybe it should be

```
re.match((u'IPv4'), line.decode('gbk'))
```

Comment: ipv4 = [line for line in myip if re.match((u'   IPv4 '), line.decode('gbk'))]# it work! differece is the space,  without the space it go wrong